# OpenGL Rotating Camera

Tags: java, opengl, camera

How would I rotate the camera(player) with the mouse? In pretty much any 3D game, you can use the mouse to look around world. Can I just use `glRotatef()` to accomplish this? Or is there a specific function that I would use to rotate the viewport?

Comment: You have *Java* as one of your tags. I assume this means you are either using LWJGL or JOGL? Either way, look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OO_yNzAuDe4&list=SP19F2453814E0E315). If you're using JOGL, this is a LWJGL tutorial, but you should be able to understand what's going on here and learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the mouse coordinates to compute in which direction you have to rotate.

For example: If you store the mouse coordinates every frame you can do something like this:

```
if (thisFrameMouse.x >= lastFrameMouse.x) {
  // mouse moved to right
} else {
  // mouse moved to left
}
```

Then you can use this information to compute a new rotation angle based on the difference of both values. With the rotation angle and a rotation axis you can create a new rotation matrix or update the existing matrix using `glRotatef` (with matrix mode `GL_MODELVIEW`, thanks to datenwolf).

If you are using GLU you can also use the [gluLookAt](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) function

Comment: I understand this part, but how do I actually rotate the camera? Do I just use `glRotatef`? Or is there a specific funtion for rotating the camera?

Comment: @micha: This is really bad advice! **The projection matrix is not meant for positioning the viewpoint!** The projection matrix is solely meant for defining the "lens" of the virtual camera.

Comment: You are right, I removed the comment and edited it into the answer. It's a long time since I used FFP the last time :-(

Answer (score 0):

That depents on the kind of view you want to have.
You can use glOrtho(): Here the depth of objects don't matter, the objects are projected on the screen parralel to the screen. You can see some examples with images when you search for glOrtho() on google images.
You can also use glLookAt(): This is the view of a human. How further objects are how less visible they are.

for the glOrtho(), you have to use glRotated and connect this correctly with your mouse.
With glLookAt it is slightly more difficult. Here you have to use some math to calculate the points to look.
The tutorials from lighthouse are good.

Keep in mind that you have to calculate the camera every frame again. Because the mouse moves.

Comment: Well thats helpful! But I use `GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, Display.getWidth() / Display.getHeight(), 1.0f, 100.0f);` to set up my view port, is this wrong? Every tutorial I've seen uses it...

Comment: Hi, gluperspective sets the mininum and maximum view distance so objects further than the maximum aren't displayed. This can be used with glLookAt.

Answer (score 0):

First you must understand that on OpenGL there is no camera!

What OpenGL does is, it takes vertex positions and puts them through a series of linear transformations (in the fixed function pipeline).

The usual pipeline is

Vertex local space position into eye space position (modelview transformation)

```
v_eye = M · v
```

from there it goes into clipspace (projection transformation)

```
v_clip = P · v_eye
```

Then it goes into normalized device coordinate (NDC) space

```
v_ndc = v_clip / v_clip.w
```

And that's it. There's no camera. So how does one define the viewport? Well think about it this way: Moving the camera in the world, or keeping the camera in position and move the whole world, there's no difference in the visual outcome. So the magic must happen somewhere in the transformation to the eye space (i.e. the position of the vertices in the view).

For this we decompose the modelview matrix M into a model-to-world part (W) and a move-world-into-view

```
M = V · W
```

So this matrix V is what defines the "camera". Lets assume that there's a camera object in the world, defined by a camera-to-world transformation C, the position of the camera object position after transformation into eyespace should be unchanged, i.e. identity

```
1 = V · C
```

and thus

```
C = V^-1
```

i.e. the view transform is the inverse of the transformation that would place a camera from the origin into the world.

---

So which OpenGL function does define the view then? None in particular. Fixed function OpenGL uses a number of matrices. And fixed function OpenGL offers primitive matrix manipulation methods, glScale, glTranslate, glRotate, which can be used to create a compound matrix. And from here you're on your own, because you must figure out yourself, how to implement the very camera transform based on the user input you want to process.

Comment: Well that all makes sense, I knew most of that before. I also know there's no real camera in OpenGL, but I'm just looking for a way to start a basic camera class. I have no idea how to do it, and I've been researching and googling stuff like crazy for the past week. Can you give me at least a few hints as to how I can do rotation?

Comment: @opiop65: Think it about this way: Your camera can be thought of a matrix that's put on the modelview matrix stack first. I wouldn't even bother with the OpenGL fixed function matrix manipulation methods (glRotate and such); they've been removed from recent versions of OpenGL altogether and nobody did use them in serious programs in the past as well. Instead you should use some matrix math library to build a camera matrix which you then load onto the stack (glLoadMatrix) and can so the rest from there.

Comment: @opiop65: Then think about how you'd move a real camera in the world and mimick that movement as a chain of transformations. To make this view as a camera matrix (instead of an object matrix), you just have to invert the resulting compound matrix.

Comment: @opiop65: As matrix math libraries I recommend Eigen, GLM or (self advertisement) linmath.h – Google finds them and hyperlinks don't work well in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use glRotatef() but you will need to calculate how much you will be rotating and where you will be rotating.